# Get packages not working because of version failing

Tags: flutter, dart

Not much to add but why would `pub get` fail with this error..

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.9.0-14.1.beta.



Because pos_app requires SDK version >=2.9.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because pos_app requires SDK version >=2.9.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Comment: what is your flutter sdk version?

Comment: `Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.` I need to be in beta channel

Comment: What was the change made before this started happening?

Comment: its a completely new install. I put my min sdk back to 2.8 and all ok now. Just thought it was strange.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, fixed switching to flutter dev channel (in my case) and upgrading version to match the requirements.
run flutter doctor -v
you'll see that your flutter sdk version runs a dart sdk that not match the project requirements, even if you installed the latest version of dart sdk on your ide. (this made me confused)